# How To Add The Help Scout javascript LiveChat from the WordPress menu

Tags: menus

My client wants to add the live chat script code from here website, but he wants it to put on the specific menu /contact-menu/ I'm not how I could implement it. please let me know any thoughts about this I'm not really familiar in javascript

this is the javascript for live chat:

```
<script type="text/javascript">!function(e,t,n){function a(){var e=t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],n=t.createElement("script");n.type="text/javascript",n.async=!0,n.src="https://beacon-v2.helpscout.net",e.parentNode.insertBefore(n,e)}if(e.Beacon=n=function(t,n,a){e.Beacon.readyQueue.push({method:t,options:n,data:a})},n.readyQueue=[],"complete"===t.readyState)return a();e.attachEvent?e.attachEvent("onload",a):e.addEventListener("load",a,!1)}(window,document,window.Beacon||function(){});</script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.Beacon('init', '602b66a1-948e-493f-b0dd-c2828b2eb860')</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: is /contact-menu/ a page?

Comment: I've moved to draft the /contact-us/ page, as for now I only put custom menu which contacts us. are they any code to put the contact menu?

Answer (score 0):

Use `add_action` to add a function to the `wp_footer` hook, and then inside the function you can check if you are on a specific page before outputting the script.

eg. the Help Scout scripts on the `/contact-us/` page:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'maybe_add_javascript');
function maybe_add_javascript() {
    if (!is_page('contact-us')) {return;}
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">!function(e,t,n){function a(){var e=t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],n=t.createElement("script");n.type="text/javascript",n.async=!0,n.src="https://beacon-v2.helpscout.net",e.parentNode.insertBefore(n,e)}if(e.Beacon=n=function(t,n,a){e.Beacon.readyQueue.push({method:t,options:n,data:a})},n.readyQueue=[],"complete"===t.readyState)return a();e.attachEvent?e.attachEvent("onload",a):e.addEventListener("load",a,!1)}(window,document,window.Beacon||function(){});</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.Beacon('init', '602b66a1-948e-493f-b0dd-c2828b2eb860')</script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Hi Majick, thank you! is this code will work? should I just copy the entire code and put on the function.php? I don't really know much on the javascript thing, it would be a great help to me if you walk me through on how I could implement step by step please?

Comment: as of now, I only add a custom menu and put an # sign, I named it "contact-us" is the code you gave will work for on custom menu?

Comment: I put the code and but it won't work, I'd created the contact us page but still wont work:(

Comment: yes you can add this to your child theme functions.php or as a file in /wp-content/mu-plugins/ ... this is based on the contact us page being a standard page with page slug of contact-us, the script will be added to the footer of that page, you can check if it is happening in the page source. if you add the page to the custom menu then when you click on it it will take you to the page where the script loads. beyond that, what the script does and how it works I have no knowledge of.